# geting the place of king in chess game

Tags: c#, winforms, chess

i m writing a simple chess game that has 3pieces,a king and a queen one side and other side just a king,the king and queen should mate alone king with less movements.in this project,first we should get the place of alone king from user and then according to that do other works,i want to know how can i get from user that in which place should king stay?i implemented form with 64 pictureboxes.i will write class for positions,thanks so much

**edited:**

i wrote this code from Mr Jon Skeet answer:
what mistake does it have?because it doesnt do anything when i click,thanks

```
PictureBox[,] pic = new PictureBox[8, 8];

public PictureBox SetKingImage(int x,int y)
    {


        pic[x,y].Image=Image.FromFile("pic/siyahsah2.JPG");
        return pic[x, y];
    }

public void GetClickedPicturebox()
    {  
        int x, y;

      for(x=0;x<8;x++)
      {
          for(y=0;y<8;y++)
          {
              pic[x, y] = new PictureBox();

              pic[x, y].Click += (object sender, System.EventArgs e) =>SetKingImage(x, y);


            }
          }
      }
```

Comment: Are you asking for suggestions on UI alternatives to allow the user to pick a location on the board (eg: enter Row-Column in the typical Chess Letter-Digit convention, click on the grid, drag and drop king image onto grid ...)  or is this about verifying the validity of a move from the King w/r the position of the opposing pieces ?

Comment: yes,im asking for UI alternatives to allow the user to pich a location,i think click on relevant picturebox is good way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to ask the user to click on the relevant picture box. You could determine which PictureBox was clicked on in one of three ways:

- Subscribe using the same event handler for each PictureBox, but use a Tag within the PictureBox to get the coordinates
- Subscribe using the same event handler for each PictureBox, but just use the reference to the PictureBox (`sender`) to find which one it was and get the coordinates appropriately
- Subscribe using a lambda expression which encapsulates the position, like this:

  ```
  for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
          pictureBoxes[x, y].Click += (sender, args) => SetKingPosition(x, y);
      }
  }
  ```

One problem with the latter approach is that unsubscribing from an event via a lambda expression is relatively painful - and you probably want to unsubscribe *all* the event handlers when the first button is clicked.

An alternative is to leave the event handlers in place, and ignore them when it's not the right time :)

Comment: @arash: The code you've given won't even compile, as you're returning from the first line of a two-line method. It's also not clear whether you ever call getclickedpicturebox. Additionally, it would help your code to read more clearly if you'd follow .NET naming conventions.

Comment: @Jon Skeet:i changed return place,i didnt understand part2 of your comment,its also clear whether....,can you learn me about it more?thanks

Comment: @arash: Your method names of "getclickedpicturebox" and "setkingposition" would normally be written as "GetClickedPictureBox" and "SetKingPosition" - so it makes it easier to see where the word breaks are.

Comment: thanks,i did it.now what other mistake do you think is in  this code that it doesnt work?thanks

Comment: @arash: Well you've still not shown the whole program. Where are you calling GetClickedPictureBox?

Comment: OMG,im so stupid,i thought this codes is enough to get the place of king,should i call GetClickedPictureBox?where should i call it?:((

Comment: @arash: At whatever point you want to start listening for the user clicking on the spot. Note that currently you'll still be listening for clicks even after the user has clicked once... and you're not *remembering* where the user clicked, just changing the image.

Comment: @Jon Skeet:i want to call GetClickedPictureBox in KingMovement class,first i will do this and then after getting relevant picturebox i want to decide to place the king up,down,....,but yet image doesnt even move before calling GetClickedPictureBoxe :(

Comment: @arash: Without seeing the whole of your code, it's impossible to say what's going on, really. But you should also consider Ran's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an idea, instead of messing with lots of PictureBoxes.

Create a UserControl called `ChessBoardControl`. The `ChessBoardControl` will take care of drawing `ChessBoard` objects that it is given.

In the `ChessBoardControl`, you can override the `OnMouseDown` event, and then from the coordinate of the mouse, you can easily calculate which square was clicked.

Comment: I completely agree with you on this being a far better design and admire your persistence. Hopefully, one of these times, you and the others will be successful in convincing arash as well.

Answer (score 1):

In your new code you have two `for` loops iterating over *i* and *j*, but in the loop you are always assigning an event handler to pic[x,y].

So you're only assigning an handler to pic[0,0]. *x* and *y* never change...

**Edit:**
Frankly I'm not sure I understand your code. What did you want the `GetClickedPicturebox` to do? And when are you calling it?

If you meant to call it in order to get the PictureBox that was clicked, it's wrong because you are attaching the event handlers to new PictureBox instances, instead of to those that are on your Form.

If this method was meant as an initialization method, then it's probably wrong because you are simply creating new PictureBox instances, but you are not showing them on your Form. If there are PictureBox on your Form, they are different instances and you did not attach the event handlers to the correct ones.